# Приложение для просмотра видео с youtube

Tags: android, youtube

Добрый день. Захотелось попробовать поработать с видео в приложениях. Появилась идея сделать приложение, которое будет воспроизводить видео с youtube, но не вызывая интентом официальное приложение. Подскажите, как это реализовать? Обязательно нужно будет работать с API youtube или это можно как-то обойти, используя спец. библиотеки?

Comment: Здесь найдете все. https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/

Comment: Вам нужее YouTubeFragment